# How can I split strings from file into smaller strings in C?

Tags: c, string, split

I have a file which looks like this:

```
text1, number, text2, text3,
text1, number, text2, text3,
...
```

I'd like to put all of these stuff into struct array:

```
struct myStruct {
    char string1[50];
    int dec;
    char string2[50];
    char string3[50];
}
```

I know that I can get line from a file using fgets() but I can't split it on smaller ones.
I can't find any understandable solution to my problem so I write my own question. I tried with strtok() but I failed. Please write as simple as you can because I'm beginner with coding.

@Edit:

Here's my strtok() attempt:

```
token = strtok(line, " ");
if(token) {
    token[strlen(token)-1] = '\0';
    strcpy(tab[counter].name, token); /* String is stored how I want it (without a comma) */
}
token = strtok(NULL, " ");

token = strtok(line, " ");
if(token) {
    token[strlen(token)-1] = '\0'; /* And here it cuts last char from previous string */
    strcpy(year_tmp, token);
    year = atoi(year_tmp);
    tab[counter].year = year; /* And nothing is stored here because it isn't even what I want */
}
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

Comment: If you show your `strtok` attempt, we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: You can use fscanf for reading word by word from a file.

Comment: I've edited my post, @ArndtJonasson

Comment: I think you may be helped by the previous question which this has been marked a duplicate of. You start with `line` and then you should keep using NULL, not restart with `line`.

Comment: Solution to that problem was too complicated for me but your suggestion worked. Thank you a lot! @ArndtJonasson